# Architecting CouchDB with nodejs

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

Does anyone have any experience with CouchDB where a real DAL was utilized?  CouchDB is not like any other datastore out there, esp. due to its notion of views which add an interesting dynamic to data - business logic separation... not to mention revision controlling the application source code.

Side Note: Libraries like Nano are not a DAL.  They are akin to a database driver.  Using Nano directly from business logic would tie the application to CouchDB.  Not what I want.  Instead my custom made DAL uses Nano as a driver, but separates the business logic from Nano completely.

Question: any best practices or documents I should read? Any existing DALs that can switch between MongoDB & CouchDB for common things (to act as a starting point for what I am trying to do)?

Comment: You should have a look at DAO libraries for CouchDB. Here is an example I wrote: [RESTDatabase](https://github.com/Hypertopic/Porphyry/blob/master/src/org/hypertopic/RESTDatabase.java), [RESTDatabaseTest](https://github.com/Hypertopic/Porphyry/blob/master/src/org/hypertopic/RESTDatabaseTest.java).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out resourceful https://github.com/flatiron/resourceful it has support for several data adapters, including mongodb and couchdb

Here is a simple use case:

```
var resourceful = require('resourceful');

var Creature = resourceful.define('creature', function () {
  //
  // Specify a storage engine
  //
  this.use('couchdb');

  //
  // Specify some properties with validation
  //
  this.string('diet');
  this.bool('vertebrate');
  this.array('belly');

  //
  // Specify timestamp properties
  //
  this.timestamps();
});

//
// Now that the `Creature` prototype is defined
// we can add custom logic to be available on all instances
//
Creature.prototype.feed = function (food) {
  this.belly.push(food);
};
```